# How to iterate an Knockout ObservableArray? (length 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-3.0

I'm new to knockout.js (and this is also my first stackoverflow post) and I'm now facing the following problem.

I'm not able to bind the data from web api to a ko.observablearray. Why is the length of this Announcements ko.observablearray always 0? The code works fine with client side data (by adding new announcements)..

Here's the JS-code:

```
var AnnouncementModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.AnnouncementText = ko.observable();
    self.AllDepartmentsBool = ko.observable();
    self.Editable = ko.observable(false);

    self.Add = function () {
        viewModel.Announcements.push(self);
        viewModel.AnnouncementToEdit(new AnnouncementModel());
    };

    self.Delete = function () {
        ajaxHelper(announcementsUri + self.ID, 'DELETE').done(
        viewModel.Announcements.remove(self));
    };

    self.Edit = function () {
        self.Editable(!self.Editable());
    };
}

//The ViewModel
function AnnouncementsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.InitialData = ko.observableArray();
    self.Announcements = ko.observableArray();
    self.AnnouncementToEdit = ko.observable(new AnnouncementModel());
    self.error = ko.observable();

    function getAllAnnouncements() {
        ajaxHelper(announcementsUri, 'GET').done(function(data) {
            self.InitialData(data);        
        });
    };

    getAllAnnouncements();
};

var viewModel = new AnnouncementsViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("announcements-container"));

function createAnnouncement(announcementDto) {
    var announcement = new AnnouncementModel();
    announcement.AnnouncementText = ko.observable(announcementDto.AnnouncementText);
    announcement.AllDepartmentsBool = ko.observable(announcementDto.AllDepartmentsBool);
    announcement.Editable = ko.observable(false);

    return announcement;
}

var length = viewModel.InitialData.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(InitialData[i]);
    viewModel.Announcements.push(newAnnouncement);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="announcements-container" style="display: inline-block; float: right">
    <ul id="announcements-list" class="newsticker" data-bind="foreach: Announcements">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="html: AnnouncementText"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_AnnouncementsModal")
</div>
```

The InitialData gets populated from the api as it should:

---

GOT IT WORKING! :

Thanks for the quick answers. I got the code working by iterating the data with .forEach(). Another problem was that the initialData didn't get populated in it's current scope so I edited the getAnnouncements function to work like this :

```
function getAllAnnouncements() {
    ajaxHelper(announcementsUri, 'GET').done(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function (entry) {
            var newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(entry);
            self.Announcements.push(newAnnouncement);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is the likely culprit:

```
var length = viewModel.InitialData.length;
```

Remember that `InitialData` is a **function**. Functions have a `length` (it's their "arity", the number of formal arguments they have), but the observable function for an observable array's `length` isn't the array's `length`..

You probably wanted the length of the array inside it:

```
var length = viewModel.InitialData().length;
// -------------------------------^^
```

Your various calls to `push` on observable arrays work even though `length` doesn't because [Knockout provides `push` (and several other things)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray) on the observable array function, as [James points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511926/hot-to-iterate-an-knockout-observablearray-length-0/34511999#comment56764790_34511999).

---

Similarly, this line:

```
var newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(InitialData[i]);
```

probably wants to be using the array as well (and is missing `viewModel.` in front of `InitialData`).

So that whole section probably wants to be refactored a bit:

```
viewModel.InitialData().forEach(function(entry) {
    var newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(entry);
    viewModel.Announcements.push(newAnnouncement);
});
```

or without `forEach` (but really, it's nearly 2016, and it's shimmable on obsolete browsers);

```
var data = viewModel.InitialData();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(data[i]);
    viewModel.Announcements.push(newAnnouncement);
}
```

---

Side note: Your code (at least as it is in the question) was also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring the `i` that you use in that `for` loop. I've added a `var` above, but this is another reason for using `forEach` to loop through arrays.

Comment: Yes, while the `observableArray` [redefines many functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray) at that level, such as `push`, so it knows when changes are happening, the `length` property isn't among them, so you need to get the underlying array for that.

Comment: omg, already loving this stackoverflow thingy.. :D Thank you T.J for a very precise and helpful answer! Got my code working with your help! I'll add the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EcmaScript 6 style enumeration as follows:

```
viewModel.InitialData().forEach(item => {
    let newAnnouncement = createAnnouncement(item);
    viewModel.Announcements.push(newAnnouncement);
});
```